# Open lightbox when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, modal-dialog

I'm using this plugin to show lightbox on a website
http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

I want to load some modal automatically when the page load.
I try using this but didn't work:

ON HEAD

```
<!-- REVEAL LIGHTBOX -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css">

<!-- script when page loads -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#flyer').reveal();
});
</script>
<!-- REVEAL LIGHTBOX -->
```

ON BODY

```
<div id="flyer" class="reveal-modal large">
  <h1>Ahora tenemos flyer y todo</h1>
  <div id="flyer-img"></div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?
This is the page that I'm working
www.cosaslindas.com/beta

Many thanks.

Comment: usually your ready function invocation goes at the end of the body.

Comment: Did  you load your jquery library in the header?

Comment: Ollie, I try putting the function at the end of the body but didn't work. Many thanks.

Comment: Michael, yes, the jQuery plugin is in the head. Also I make the call in some buttons on the body and the modal appears with no problems (click on "Ampliar flyer" on the sidebar to see the example).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code I've tried it in jsfiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/NsQpM/ you might have some other code or styling that causes it to not work. I would try to remove other js and css. Test and keep adding until it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this after the `$('#flier').reveal();`

```
$('#flier').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I tried this on his website using firebug but just triggering a click wont work. The js binds to a tags with the data-reveal-id attribute.

Comment: @Michael If you add it using firebug it won't work because the element is already bound. I've tested this and it does work. I set up a test page to try it out and it works perfectly. [Try it here](http://johnwebb.info/dev/test/scroll.php)

Comment: Oh, I see that in your example works fine! What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm. The error I get is that reveal is not a function. I know it's not supposed to matter, but I have noticed that sometimes `$` needs to be replaced by `jQuery`. That seems like a long shot, but it's worth a try. I'll look a little more to see what could be causing the problem.

Comment: I know what's causing the problem. You're calling the jQuery library twice. Once before and once after the reveal. I just added the second one to my test page and it quit working. Get rid of the second jQuery library.

Comment: Cool! Is fixed. Thanks for your help John

Answer (score 0):

[This issue on Github explains how to do it.](https://github.com/zurb/reveal/issues/16) It's not a feature of Reveal, but it looks like it can be used to work. You need to have an element (in your case, `#flyer` have the attribute "data-reveal-onready").

Answer (score 0):

Ive been looking to the modal plugin and i think the reveal function will only bind to a tags with the data-reveal-id attribute.

Not sure if this will work but i'd say give it a try!

add to you html:

```
<a id="triggerflyermodal" href="#" data-reveal-id="flyer" style="display:none">This is hidden</a>
```

And change the call to this:

```
<!-- script when page loads -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#triggerflyermodal').click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael I try but didn't work. Look http://cosaslindas.com/beta/try2.html ¿Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Your loading jQuery library twice!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

And

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Trying removing the last one.

Edit2:
I just tested this in jsfiddle. If you remove the 2nd jquery library from your header your script should run fine!

Comment: @motoxer yep soz i didnt see the top one :O overlooked it. I noticed hes loading jquery library twice. This might be conflicting.

Comment: Thanks Michael! And thanks to everybody to help me. http://cosaslindas.com/beta/ works perfectly, it was oly change the order of js's. Have a great weekend. I'm not a JS coder and this site and people like you help me a lot, and is so quicky. THANKS.